# How to add textures to a .obj file?

Tags: modeling

I am trying to make a hat for a game called Bloxcity. Anyway how to have textures on .obj files?

Comment: I believe the obj exporter includes textures by default. What have you tried and in what way did it not work?

Comment: It never shows the texture in 3D Builder.

Comment: Do other obj files correctly retain their textures in 3D builder?

Comment: It askes for a texture for other .obj files but i cant find the texture for em.